# Reference to member 'date' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm fetching and using the data from CoreData in SwiftUI.
When I use it:

```
ForEach(reminders) { reminder in
    if Calendar.current.isDate(reminder.date.wrappedValue, inSameDayAs: selectedDate) {
        RoundedRectangleView(
           reminderName: reminder.name,
           selectedTime: reminder.time,
           selectedColor: Color(reminder.color ?? .green)
        )
        }
    }
```

Under the reminder.date.wrappedValue, it says:

```
Reference to member 'date' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
```

For reminder.date, I defined:

```
class Reminder: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var date: Date
    @NSManaged var time: Date
    @NSManaged var color: String? /
}
```

For selectedDate, I have:

```
@State private var selectedDate = Date()
```

Please help me, how to fix this error?

Need someone help me to fix an error

Comment: Where is the declaration of your `reminder` variable? (Not the `Reminder` type, but the variable `reminder` that I assume is an observable object?)

Comment: Why `wrappedValue` when you don’t use that for any of the other properties?

Comment: Looks like the issue is not returning a view in case the `if` condition fails